# About modal view behavior

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

I'm making modal view.
What I want to do is to wait until modal view is dismissed.
Here's the code.

```
    SelecYourCountryViewController *selecYourCountryViewController = [[SelecYourCountryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelecYourCountryViewController" bundle:nil];
    selecYourCountryViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self.presentingViewController presentViewController:selecYourCountryViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"select your contry");
```

At this code, despite of modalview(selecYourCountryViewController) is alive, process goes next step.
In short, NSLog is shown while selecYourCountryViewController is working.
 Please let me know the way of wait until view is dismissed and get returning value.

(It's like Msgbox on VisualBasic behavior)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you meant by "wait until modal view is dismissed", but I think what you need is to use delegate callback protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The simple-minded answer is: implement `viewWillAppear:`. One of the reasons this view will appear is that the presented view disappeared.

The more complex and correct answer is: It is up to you to set things up so that if *this* controller needs to hear about it when the presented view controller is dismissed, the presented view controller has a way to send this controller a message telling it that it is being dismissed. Look at the Utility app template in Xcode to see how this can be done: the presenting controller hands the presented controller a reference to itself, so that the presented controller can send it a message before dismissal.

You might also like to read the discussion in my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_presented_view_controller

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I read your article over and over. Then I'm editing whole code.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm sympathetic for your longing for the convenience of VB's `MsgBox`, bottom line, that's not how it works in iOS (for some good reasons). The right way for the secondary view controller to tell the first view controller that something is done is via delegation. (See [Using Delegation to Communicate with Other Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW9) in the *View Controller Programming Guide.*) Or you can otherwise have the secondary view actually trigger the next step itself.

If you try the upon `viewWillAppear`, you have to determine why it appeared, i.e. the initial appearance, because the secondary view was successful and has been dismissed, because the secondary view was canceled and dismissed, etc. Also, be wary that if you ever convert to iPad app and use a popover, remember that you won't get the `viewWillAppear` method when the popover is dismissed, etc.). Just a few little things to be aware of.